# How to subtract two amounts in C# of two different types - decimal and double?

Tags: c#, types, double, decimal, subtraction

I have the following method that passes an amount in as follows

```
public async Task<Debit> ExecuteAsync(DebitCommand command)
        {
            Debit resp = new Debit();
          resp.debitamount=command.debitamount
           // do some code here that gets a user account balance from db

            //debit the account and get new balance
            var newBalance=(AccountBalance - debitAmount ) // 10256.65 -10  new balance =10246.65
            return resp; ;
        }
```

the `debitAmount` is a **double**

the `AccountBalance` is a **decimal**

How do I subtract the both to give me the new balance?

Comment: AccountBalance - (decimal)debitAmount

Comment: You should never use double to represent money, is it possible to refactor?

Comment: the way we perform ***any*** operation in C# between ***any*** two different types is that we first convert one type to be the same as the other.